# Match closest equal or preceding timestamp

Tags: shell-script, timestamps

I have a series of timestamps representing events, e.g.:

```
20150401_1120    // event a
20150401_1211    // event b
```

And a series of logfiles, each representing a fixed period of time and timestamped with the start of that period, e.g.:

```
$ ls | egrep -o [0-9]{8}_[0-9]{4}
```

gives:

```
20150401_1100
20150401_1120    // contains event a
20150401_1140
20150401_1200    // contains event b
20150401_1220
```

I want to get the logfiles containing events, i.e. with the same timestamp as the event or the closest preceding timestamp. Is there some command or trick to do this efficiently?

With efficiently I mean not having to write a lot. :)

Comment: Are the time-stamps stored in another file? and the second portion of code you pasted, is that the output of `ls` ? Is the time-stamp inside the log file or as a part of the file name?

Comment: Yes, the timestamps are stored in another file (or extracted from is more correct) and yes the second part is cleaned-up `ls` output. The timestamp for the logfile is in the filename, the logfile data itself is in a binary format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's call `ue` the file with event timestamps, and `ul` the file with the logs.

I came up with a very intuitive way:

```
( awk '{printf "%s a\n",$1 }' ul ; awk '{printf "%s b\n",$1 }' ue ) |\
 sort |\
 awk '/b/ { print before ;} /a/ { before=$1 ;} '
```

Which

- adds a tag to list of events and timestamps, you can use any tag, but logfile tag must come before event tag. (*)
- merges by sort.
- awk retrieves previous log file.

Result are:

```
20150401_1120
20150401_1200
```

(*) some clever `sort` option might be user to sort column one by ascending order and column two by descending order (to put 'log' before 'event' in case timestamp match )

Comment: Nice! This is what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: If anyone wants to match succeeding (or equal) timestamps, use `sort -r` to reverse the sort order. Would upvote if I had the rep.